# What is modern fire alarm cable made of?

Tags: wire

I'm curious about the fire alarm cable that's being installed in a new building next to my office.

In the fairly distant past, I learned that fire alarm cable was "pryo" cable. Under the red jacket it was a copper tube containing two conductors, all mutually insulated by a white mineral powder. Apparently it would stay working unless a fire melted the copper, because there was nothing inside that could burn or decompose.

What they are using today appears to have layers of polymers. Under the red outer layer is a stiff white jacket. Inside is a bare (earth?) wire and two wires insulated with blue and brown polymer.

What are these polymer materials, and what happens to them in a fire? Was the "pyro" cable deemed overkill and used only for lack of alternatives to PVC in past decades?

Comment: hm, what does you finding this type of cable now have to do with "pyro cable"  being deemed overkill?

Comment: Perhaps that "new" cable has a sufficiently high melting point that people are already dead before the cable melts... At that point the alarm looses its usefulness...

Comment: Meh. If the cable melts you'll get an alarm anyway. No worries! (I actually used to work on these systems but only did the firmware so can't answer your question about the cable)

Comment: @Marcus-Müller fire alarm cabling is obviously required to be highly resistant to damage. The old pyro cable seemed perfect on this front. I'm guessing that a polymer-insulated cable will fail before a fire gets hot enough to melt copper. So assuming the polymer cable meets fire safety regulations, doesn't that imply that pyro cable was overkill? But I'm mostly interested in what these polymers actually are, and what conditions they can survive.

Comment: @solar-Mike you can have a very intense fire contained in one part of a building, and you don't want a cable failure to turn off the alarms in other parts of the building. My understanding, which may be faulty, is that alarms are connected in parallel.

Comment: @nigel222 point is that the copper tube thing might still have its place! For example, you really don't need to make the cable to a single alarm button resistant up to 1000°C – no one is going to press that button if the last 5m to that button are that high. If you, however, have some sort of central cable distribution, it would make a lot of sense if temperatures that high in that specific room wouldn't end the ability of someone to sound the fire alarm. So, maybe your pyro cable is overkill for one application, but not for another.

Comment: @nigel222 Alarms are usually connected in a loop, each end of the loop connected to the central. If the cable breaks in the middle, it doesn't affect functionality because each end has a connection back to the central. It's only a problem if it breaks in two places, every sensor in between the two breaks are now isolated.

Comment: @pipe that makes perfect sense, as long as the wire can't fail short-circuited. Which comes back to my question about  insulation that might  combust or decompose.

Comment: @nigel222 If it's shorted out it's also detected as "defective", the sensors we used were designed so that they would internally disconnect the shorted out segment so it would be handed roughly in the same way as a break. But of course, it's better if the cable is healthy as long as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like FP200 or similar.

The copper tube with mineral insulation was MICC cable.

MICC is a pain in the arse to terminate which is why no installer likes doing it if they have any choice, and the modern synthetics have good enough properties in a fire to make them compliant with the appropriate standards and are not hydroscopic if incorrectly terminated.

MICC tended to fail insulation test after a while if the person fitting the potting gland on the end was not taking sufficient care.

There are multiple vendors of modern fire alarm cables and they all have their own trademarks and 'secret sauce' chemistry.

Comment: "secret sauce" ... so that's why my Googling failed!

Answer (score 1):

Fire alarm cable can use a variety of insulations depending on application.  Some is made from ordinary PVC and others of XLPE (cross linked polyethylene) or XLVA (look it up), silicone and even Teflon.
Some cable is made to fail in a fire.  The insulation melts, the conductors touch and that triggers the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

The flexible [cables](http://www.ucable.com.my/images/products/UC%20Fire%20Resistant%20Catalogue.pdf) (image below from this link) you saw probably have a layer of Mica as insulator in there (which is a 960°C safe mineral isolator). Some of them can withstand close to 1000°C for up to 3 hours.

[image: Cable from above catalogue]

However, that's under the assumption that no external pressure (e.g. from parts of the cable housing falling onto them) is applied to them.

One way to ensure that would be putting them in safe metal tube – and that's basically what the mineral powder filled tubes are. If you, however, ensure that there won't be other things failing and scraping the mica insulation off the cable, then you don't have need for any copper tubing!

Also, if you look at the picture above, you can see an aluminium "wire armour"– practically your tube-to-go!

So, if you have a metal cable conduct, then you're pretty safe: most of the other cables' isolation will be gone the moment the flame-retardiant silicone rubber of your fire alarm cable gives in, so these cable will have reached a somewhat "stationary" pose. The risk of one of them changing position sharply enough to scrape of insulation is small. Same if the cable is running alone on some plaster wall.

So: fire-proofing cables is a process, not only a material :) Your flexible cables might be very well as safe as metal tubes filled with mineral powder for some use cases, moreso in others (think about non-fire-related failures, like water ingress), less in mechanically difficult situations. It's maybe less about over-kill, but about safety of installation.

Comment: No, this isn't what I saw. No armour. Outer jacket is a quite stiff white material (coloured red on exterior),, has aluminium foil on inner surface. Two inner wires insulated brown and blue with a very elastic material (silicone rubber at a guess) with a single copper core. Third uninsulated wire.